# Node.js cache data in file on server

Tags: node.js

I want to store data in files on the server. The filename will be a encrypted version of the request and the data to be served the file's contents.

I'm using Node.js to process data and send it to the client. I want to be able to send the same processed data when a similar request is received again.

What can I use that is suitable for such a requirement?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `fs`?

Comment: any code of how you deel currently with the request?

Comment: @aug Yes, I'm aware about fs. I am looking for a readily available npm that does this.

Comment: is this not what http servers do? serve files? Cache them (use http headers). Encrypt them with certificates TLS, SSL? so nginx, apache, or one of these server proxied ot your node app.